# How can the main function have 2 declarations/definitions in C?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

The `main()` function in C has multiple definitions.

```
int main (void) { body }    (1) 
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { body }  (2)
```

(https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

How is this possible since C cannot have multiple declarations/definitions of the same function?

Comment: You're misreading the doc.  There can be only one `main` function, and there are 2 valid signature for it.

Comment: To answer the question you *actually* asked (rather than the one you meant to ask): "weak linkage" is a thing in most compilers.

Comment: @WilliamPursell In C, function cannot have more than one valid signature, right?

Comment: An arbitrary function can have any (valid) signature.  You can write `int foo(void)` or `char * foo(int, char **)` or `void foo(int, int *)` or... anything.  But `main` must be either `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char **)`.  In any program, there can be only one main, and its signature must be one of those two.

Comment: Note that [Annex J.5.1 Environment arguments](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.1) recognizes a common extension whereby `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)` is valid, and the `envp` argument points to a null-terminated array of environment variable strings (`ENV_VAR=value`).  On a Mac, there can be a fourth argument too, also with a list of strings, for Apple-specific information: `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **applev)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `main` function is special in that is called by the runtime, and as such it is allowed to have one of those two signatures but not both at once.

Presumably, the runtime pushes the required arguments onto the stack as part of the call to `main` which doesn't have to use them.  Since this is considered part of the implementation it can do things normal programs can't (or shouldn't) ordinarily do.